# How to use trace.json written by ChromeDriver

Tags: json, google-chrome, trace, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a simple `node` script which starts `chromedriver` pointed at my website, scrolls to the bottom of the page, and writes the trace to `trace.json`.

This file is around 30MB.

I can't seem to load this file in `chrome://tracing/`, which is what I assume I would do in order to view the profile data.

What are my options for making sense of my `trace.json` file?

Here is my `node` script, in case that helps clarify what I am up to:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var wd = require('wd');
var b = wd.promiseRemote('http://localhost:9515');

b.init({
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    perfLoggingPrefs: {
      'traceCategories': 'toplevel,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame,blink.console,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline,benchmark'
    },
    args: ['--enable-gpu-benchmarking', '--enable-thread-composting']
  },
  loggingPrefs: {
    performance: 'ALL'
  }
}).then(function () {
  return b.get('http://www.example.com');
}).then(function () {
  // We only want to measure interaction, so getting a log once here
  // flushes any previous tracing logs we have.
  return b.log('performance');
}).then(function () {
  // Smooth scroll to bottom.
  return b.execute(`
    var height = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    chrome.gpuBenchmarking.smoothScrollBy(height, function (){});
  `);
}).then(function () {
  // Wait for the above action to complete.
  return b.sleep(5000);
}).then(function () {
  // Get all the trace logs since last time log('performance') was called.
  return b.log('performance');
}).then(function (data) {
  // Write the file to disk.
  return fs.writeFileSync('trace.json', JSON.stringify(data.map(function (s) {
    return JSON.parse(s.message); // This is needed since Selenium outputs logs as strings.
  })));
}).fin(function () {
  return b.quit();
}).done();
```

Comment: Is the file correctly generated? are you able to load it manually?

Comment: Load it manually how? The file itself is huge, so hard to say if it is correctly generated, but it "looks" OK. Proper JSON, etc.

Comment: To load it manually: Start Chrome, go to chrome://tracing/ and click Load.

Comment: Right. That is the issue. That is what I have been trying to do. I think it may be best to use `browser-perf` rather than trying to roll my own solution. I'm pretty sure that package scrubs the data for use in chrome.

Comment: My bad, I thought you were loading it by code.

Answer (score 4):

Your script doesn't generate the correct format. The required data for each entry are located in `message.message.params`.

To generate a trace that can be loaded in chrome://tracing :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities({
    browserName : 'chrome',
    loggingPrefs : { performance: 'ALL' },
    chromeOptions : {
      args: ['--enable-gpu-benchmarking', '--enable-thread-composting'],
      perfLoggingPrefs: {
        'traceCategories': 'toplevel,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame,blink.console,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline,benchmark'
      }
    }
  }).build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.sleep(1000);

// generate a trace file loadable in chrome://tracing
driver.manage().logs().get('performance').then(function (data) {
  fs.writeFileSync('trace.json', JSON.stringify(data.map(function (d) {
    return JSON.parse(d['message'])['message']['params'];
  })));
});

driver.quit();
```

The same script with python:

```
import json, time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities = {
  'loggingPrefs': { 'performance': 'ALL' },
  'chromeOptions': {
    "args" : ['--enable-gpu-benchmarking', '--enable-thread-composting'],
    "perfLoggingPrefs" : {
      "traceCategories": "toplevel,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame,blink.console,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline,benchmark"
    }
  }
})

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
time.sleep(1)

# generate a trace file loadable in chrome://tracing
with open(r"trace.json", 'w') as f:
  f.write(json.dumps([json.loads(d['message'])['message']['params'] for d in driver.get_log('performance')]))

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you know, the recommendation lib for parsing those thing is https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend

Also, recommended categories are `__metadata,benchmark,devtools.timeline,rail,toplevel,disabled-by-default-v8.cpu_profiler,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame,blink.user_timing,v8.execute,disabled-by-default-devtools.screenshot`

It's very old question, but hope this helps new other guys.